# saw this in a video referenced as an alternative to anonymous inner class, what is it?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```
private val playbackEventListener = object : YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener {

    override fun onPlaying() {
        Toast.makeText(this@YoutubeActivity, "onPlaying called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun onPaused() {
        Toast.makeText(this@YoutubeActivity, "onPaused called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun onStopped() {

        Toast.makeText(this@YoutubeActivity, "onStopped called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun onBuffering(p0: Boolean) {
    }

    override fun onSeekTo(p0: Int) {
    }
}
```

If this is not an anonymous inner class then what is the declaration on line 1 called and is it an appropriate alternative?  Also what is up with

```
this@YouTubeActivity
```

why can't "this" be used

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the link to the video? Maybe you misunderstood the video, and the context in which this was said can give more information.

Answer (score 1):

That is an anonymous class, it's [just the way Kotlin does them](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/objects-and-companion-objects.html#object-expressions)

> By using an *object expression*, you can now define an anonymous, unnamed class and at the same time create one instance of it, called an *anonymous object*:

The `this@YouTubeActivity` thing is because you're inside the scope of that anonymous class/object, so `this` refers to the object. Since you want to refer to the activity, which is `this` in an outer scope, you have to specify which `this` you're talking about.

It comes up a lot where you have nested functions and lambdas, and receivers, and `this` gets redefined (or shadowed), and you might need the reference to an outer, enclosing object as well. So `this@WhateverThing` gives you the ability to reference them easily without having to create a `val myActivity = this` or whatever in advance

Comment: this makes a lot of sense, i'm thinking the person in the video meant to say that it is an alternative to a Java anonymous inner class

Comment: Yeah maybe! Or they could have been contrasting it with the more Kotlin-y way of doing things, which is to pass lambdas and function references around directly, instead of creating an an anonymous class just so you can put a function inside it (and maybe having to define an interface for it too). It's not really an *alternative* to the Java approach, it's the same thing just done in Kotlin, and makes it easier to use Java and Kotlin code together. Can't say what the person actually meant though

Comment: Although I'll say, in your example, that's one of the things they talk about in the link - if you have an interface with a lot of callback functions that need defining at once, it can be more useful to just create one object like that, instead of passing in multiple callback functions separately. So they could have meant **that** was an alternative way of doing things. (And if it was originally designed in Java, they're more likely to have done it that way, because having separate callback objects would mean multiple anonymous classes implementing a single function).